# Highcharts define colors for each data point in a pair

Tags: highcharts

I want to define two custom colours, one for male and another for female.

I have a simple column chart that charts males and females by age. There are 7 pairs of data points. Meaning 1 pair of data points for males and females aged 0-39, another pair for males and females aged 40-49, and so on.The default chart colors are light blue and black.

I want to change these colors, let's say to green and orange. colorByPoint doesn't meet my needs, since it colors every data pair a different color. What is the solution?

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Average Life Expectancy'
        },
        xAxis: {

            categories: ['0-39', '40-49', '50-59', '60-69', '70-79', '80-89', '90+'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Breakdown by gender',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
              colorByPoint: true,

                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }

            }


        },

        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 80,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Males',
            data: [10, 7, 4, 12, 27, 21, 2],


        }, {
            name: 'Females',
            data: [10, 3, 5, 12, 15, 10, 11]
        }]

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
series: [{
        name: 'Males',
        data: [10, 7, 4, 12, 27, 21, 2],
        color: '#008000'

    }, {
        name: 'Females',
        data: [10, 3, 5, 12, 15, 10, 11],
        color: "#FFA500"
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to simple define a color for the series:

```
  series: [{
    ...,
    color: 'green'
  }, {
    ...,
    color: "orange"
  }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4934/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.color